# Formula for radius of convergence in different co-ordinates:

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

A problem that I'm doing asks for the formula for the tangential polar coordinate system with the radial distance $r$ and the perpendicular distance from a fixed point $O$ to the tangent to the curve at a general point $P$ is given.

[image]

To find the radius of convergence, I've done the following:
By the law of cosines,
$ c^2 = r^2 + \rho^2 - 2r\rho \cos (OPC);$

And

$c^2 = (r+∆r)^2 + \rho^2 +-2(r+∆r)\rho \cos (OQC)$

$\cos (OPC) = p/r$

And

$ \cos (OQC) = (p+∆p)/ (r+∆r);$

Substituting, and equating $c^2$, we get:
$(r+∆r)^2 + \rho^2 - 2(p+∆p)\rho = 
c^2 = r^2 + \rho^2 - 2p\rho$

Then on solving, we get:

$\rho =  r ∆r/∆p - (∆r)^2/(2∆p)$

And in the limit that $Q$ tends to $P$, $∆r$ and $∆p$ becomes $dr$ and $dp$ and we get:

$\rho = r dr/dp - (dr)^2/(2dp)$

But the answer is
$\rho = r dr/dp$. Do we just consider $(dr)^2/(2dp)$ to be zero?

Also, on solving this question, I had a doubt. Can anyone find the formula for radius of convergence in spherical coordinates? I wanted some insights on this since I tried and failed.

Comment: the law of cosines is
$ c^2 = r^2 + \rho^2 - 2r\rho \cos (OPC)$

Comment: Oops. Correct. But there is still a $(∆r)^2$ term remaining. Do we just consider it as zero?